# What are the differences between IPO and Direct Listing, esp for employees?

Tags: united-states, stock-valuation, employee-stock-options, ipo, comparison

If a pre-IPO company is evaluating whether they should go IPO or Direct Listing, how would either option affect employees? Let's say the employees have some combination of NSO, ISO, RSU.

IPO may be a little more straight-forward but I am not familiar with Direct Listing. Could you go over best/worst case with some numbers to help understand?